# Is WPF yet another GUI toolkit like WinForms?

Tags: .net, wpf, gui-toolkit

Is WPF yet another GUI toolkit like WinForms with some enhanced features? What other GUI toolkits are available for .Net? I am new to .Net and I believe that WinForms is a GUI Toolkit as per: http://www.mono-project.com/Gui_Toolkits

Comment: WPF is indeed the most recent Desktop GUI toolkit for Windows OS

Comment: @LuisFilipe - almost, WinRT is the most recent Desktop GUI ;-)

Comment: Thanks Luis Filepe and ColinE!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From (the very first sentence of) [Wikipedia's page on WPF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Presentation_Foundation):

> Developed by Microsoft, the Windows Presentation Foundation (or WPF)
>   is a computer-software graphical subsystem for rendering user
>   interfaces in Windows-based applications

So ... yes.

Other GUI toolkits for .NET include

- Windows Forms
- Windows Presentation Foundation
- ASP.NET
- Silverlight

Comment: This correctly answers the first part of the question: `Is WPF yet another GUI toolkit?`. The answer to the second part, `Is WPF [...] like WinForms with some enhanced features?` is a resounding NO. It is in no way based on WinForms. It is a GUI toolkit completely built from scratch with a vastly different feature set, and in my opinion, not even comparable to WinForms.